# Xmonad Layout with vertically stacked secondary tiles

Tags: xmonad

I'm looking for a layout for use on a portrait oriented monitor that would look roughly like this (warning bad ascii art):

```
|------------|
|            |
|  master    |
|            |
|------------|
| secondary  |
|------------|
| secondary  |
|------------|
| secondary  |
|------------|
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a good option in xmonad-contrib:

http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-Column.html

```
myLayoutHook = Column 2.0 ||| ...
```

play with the number `2.0` to suit your screen size